Can't connect to Reactotron from expo phyisical device with tunneling
I am trying to use Reactotron for debugging my React Native Expo app. I am using a phyisical device, not an emulator and I am running expo with tunneling option to connect, so my URL is generated by ngrok.
What I am doing wrong?
index.tsx (main entry point in my app)
if (__DEV__) {
    import("@/app/dev/ReactotronConfig").then(() => {
        console.log("Reactotron Configured");
    });
}

ReactotronConfig.js
import Reactotron from "reactotron-react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

import { asyncStorage } from 'reactotron-react-native';
Reactotron.setAsyncStorageHandler(AsyncStorage)
    .configure({ name: "React Native Demo", }) // controls connection & communication settings
    .use(asyncStorage())
    .useReactNative() // add all built-in react native plugins
    .connect(); // let's connect!

